# how to use regular expression to remove punctuations in a string

Tags: java, regex

I write a Java program to remove all punctuations in the string

```
"1.1 Interactive systems  In today's world, interacting with computer-based devices and systems is commonplace."
```

How can I use regex to remove the punctuations to have this string

```
"11 Interactive systems  In todays world interacting with computerbased devices and systems is commonplace".
```

Comment: These two sentences appear to have little in common with each other?  Do you have a typo in your question?

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using String's [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) with regex:**

```
String mystring = "\"1.1 Interactive systems  In today's world, interacting with computer-based devices and systems is commonplace.\"";

String replaced = mystring.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");
```

Actual regex is `\p{Punct}` but we need to escape `\` hence another back slash.

**Output:**

```
11 Interactive systems  In todays world interacting with computerbased devices and systems is commonplace
```

Comment: `\p{Punct}` already represents characters set, there is no point in putting it into another character set `[..]` (just like it is pointless to use `[\d]` instead of simple `\d`), so you can remove `[` and `]` from this regex. BTW you have extra `)` at the end.

Comment: Thank you for explaining with example!  made corrections.